# Multiple request filtr from url Djjango

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get items filtered by the category ID which is obtained from request Django. it looks like this:

```
   url(r'^productlist.aspx&category(?P<category>\d*)$', 'shop.views.shoplist'),
```

so in url it looks like:

```
http://example.com/store/productlist.aspx&category6
```

Where "6" is the category ID

and here is the views.py

```
def shoplist(request, category, format=None):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['products'] =  ShopProduct.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    if category:
        args['products'] = ShopProduct.objects.filter(shop_product_category_id = category)
    return render_to_response('shop-catlist.html', args)
```

It works good, but niw I want to filter products by multiple category ID's

in url it will looks like this: `http://example.com/store/store.aspx&category1,2,3,4,5`

Please help me

Note: The category ID's will be collected via checkboxes in form, and url will be generated according to the selected checkboxes with JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't format the URL like that. There is a perfectly suitable way of passing queries in URLs, and that is to use a querystring:

```
http://example.com/store/productlist/?category=1&category=2&category=3
```

(Also, why are you pretending your Django site is running on .NET? Don't do that.)

Now your URL pattern just looks like this:

```
url(r'^productlist/$', 'shop.views.shoplist'),
```

and your view is:

```
def shoplist(request):
    categories = request.GET.getlist('category')
    if categories:
       products = ShopProduct.objects.filter(shop_product_category_id__in=categories)
```

Comment: Hmmm, is there any way to pass "?" or use something instead? Because the url pattern which I provided is the simplifyed one, in original it looks like `url(r'^productlist.aspx&shop(?P<shop>\d*)&category(?P<category>\d*)&subcategory(?P<subcategory>\d*)&discount(?P<discount>\d*)$', 'shop.views.shoplist'),`

Comment: Which is exactly why you shouldn't be doing those in the URL, but as query args.

Comment: 'example.com/store/productlist/?category=1&category=2&category=3?subcategory=1&subcategory=4&subcategory=13' is it ok to show different argument queries like this?

Comment: Yes, that is how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, you only need one question mark: `/productlist/?category=1&store=2 `